# Control group of coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I would like to gather some coroutines inside a group, so that group.stop() would stop all co-routines. Is there a way to do so ?

If I was to manually do it, I would use a set of coroutines, and I would wrap all my coroutines so that they are removed from the set when they finish naturally. But this wrapping sounds like a performance hit.

Ideally, I would like to define a sub-reactor (MonoBehaviour) containing my coroutines, and then treat the sub-reactor as a coroutine, allowing to start and stop it from the main reactor.

Thank you !

Comment: what about storing them in a list or Dictionary?

Comment: How to pop them automatically from this container when they finish ? My coroutines stop after a few seconds / minutes, but I keep creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

So what you could do for example is storing them in a Dictionary like

```
private Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,Coroutine>> routines = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,Coroutine>>();
```

So the outer dictionary is a group of routines, the inner Dictionary links each Coroutine to a unique routineIndex within this group.

So when you start a routine you pass in the `IEnumerator` and the group index you want to start it in.

The routine itself is then executed nested within a general worker routine which automatically removes the according routine by the groupIndex and routine index from the `routines` Dictionary:

```
public void StartRoutine(int groupIndex, IEnumerator routine)
{
    if (!routines.ContainsKey(groupIndex))
    {
        routines.Add(groupIndex, new Dictionary<int, Coroutine>());
    }

    // Get next available index within group
    var routineIndex = 0;
    while (routines[groupIndex].ContainsKey(index))
    {
        routineIndex++;
    }

    routines[groupIndex].Add(routineIndex, StartCoroutine(Worker(routineIndex, index,  routine)));
}

// pass in the group and routine index
// so each worker "instance" knows exactly
// which entry to remove from the routines
// Dictionary when it is done
private IEnumerator Worker(int groupIdx, int routineIdx, IEnumerator routine)
{
    yield return routine;

    // when done remove from dictionary
    routines[groupIdx].Remove(routineIdx);
}
```

Now you can stop all routines by group index useing e.g.

```
public void Stop(int groupIdx)
{
    if(!routines.ContainsKey(groupIdx)) return;

    foreach (var routine in routines[groupIdx].Values)
    {
        StopCoroutine(routine);
    }

    routines.Remove(groupIdx);
}
```

---

To make things easier instead of an `int` for the groupIndex you could replace it by an `enum` like e.g.

```
public enum GroupID
{
    GroupA,
    GroupB,
    etc
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone and not tested but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot. i was afraid of the overhead if I had to wrap every iteration of routine in Worker, but I forgot I could yield the routine itself, so the overhead is acceptable.

Comment: One thing that was never clear to me is that you should not start a coroutine with IEnumerator then stop it with a Coroutine, yet there is no way to instantiate a Coroutine without StartCoroutine method

Comment: This is why we need the routineIdx, to match which Coroutine to stop based on an identifier of a call to Worker.

Comment: Yes but look you are starting it with this method `StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)` and stopping it with `StopCoroutine(Coroutine)`, which according to Unity is not a good idea, yet there is no way to start a coroutine with a `Coroutine` object